# Windows event id for battery level change

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, battery, events

I need to create a task in TS based on battery level change.
Let's say my battery drops from **67%** to **66%**. How can I run a task based on this event. Does Windows log this at all? I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: WIndows 10 (and preferably W7 as well)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### I need to create a task in Task Scheduler based on battery level change

Windows doesn't log this kind of detail as events. You can however use something like the batch file below and create a custom event.

---

#### Battery.cmd

This batch file monitors the current battery percentage charge and creates a user defined event if the charge drops below a user defined threshold value.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem set threshold value
set _threshold=82
:start
rem get the battery charge
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1" %%i in (`wmic Path Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _charge=%%i
  echo !_charge!
  if !_charge! lss !_threshold! (
    echo threshold reached
    rem create a custom event in the application event log
    rem requires administrator privileges 
    eventcreate /l APPLICATION /t WARNING /ID 999 /D "Battery charge has dropped"
    goto :done
    ) else (
    rem wait for 10 minutes then try again
    timeout /t 600 /nobreak
    goto :start
    )
  )
:done
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The `Eventcreate` command works on Windows XP up to and including Windows 10, it requires administrator privileges to work
- Set `_threshold` as required
- If the battery falls below this value an event with ID `999` will be generated in the APPLICATION event log with the description `Battery charge has dropped`
- Modify the `eventcreate` command as required for your situation.
- Modify the `timeout` delay as required for your situation.

**Example output:**

My battery currently has a charge of 81%. I set the threshold to `82`. Here is what happens when I run `Battery.cmd`:

```
> battery
81
threshold reached

SUCCESS: An event of type 'WARNING' was created in the 'APPLICATION' log with 'EventCreate' as the source.
```

And here is the new entry in the Event Log:

[image]

---

#### eventcreate syntax

```
EVENTCREATE [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] /ID eventid
            [/L logname] [/SO srcname] /T type /D description

Description:
    This command line tool enables an administrator to create
    a custom event ID and message in a specified event log.

Parameter List:
    /S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U    [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which
                           the command should execute.

    /P    [password]       Specifies the password for the given
                           user context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    /L    logname          Specifies the event log to create
                           an event in.

    /T    type             Specifies the type of event to create.
                           Valid types: SUCCESS, ERROR, WARNING, INFORMATION.

    /SO   source           Specifies the source to use for the
                           event (if not specified, source will default
                           to 'eventcreate'). A valid source can be any
                           string and should represent the application
                           or component that is generating the event.

    /ID   id               Specifies the event ID for the event. A
                           valid custom message ID is in the range
                           of 1 - 1000.

    /D    description      Specifies the description text for the new event.

    /?                     Displays this help message.


Examples:
    EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 1000
        /L APPLICATION /D "My custom error event for the application log"

    EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 999 /L APPLICATION
        /SO WinWord /D "Winword event 999 happened due to low diskspace"

    EVENTCREATE /S system /T ERROR /ID 100
        /L APPLICATION /D "Custom job failed to install"

    EVENTCREATE /S system /U user /P password /ID 1 /T ERROR
        /L APPLICATION /D "User access failed due to invalid user credentials"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [eventcreate](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-an-event-in-event-viewer/) - Create a Custom Event in the Windows Event Viewer.
- [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: I really like this! From your POV, it's better to create events and run event based task (e.g. PS script)? Or... modify this script to run my PS script, if battery level drops by 1%. I assumed that Windows is creating events for battery level change. I didn't think about this approach, which might be better.

Comment: @MiHa Up to you. Whichever is easiest to understand and maintain :)

Comment: @MiHa [Logging power / battery events](//stackoverflow.com/q/18514076), http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=battstat_xp and http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=battrun_xp and might also be worth a read

Answer (score 7):

There is a `Microsoft-Windows-Battery` ETW provider with `BatteryPercentRemaining` event with ID 13. You can code a project that uses [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) to create a [realtime listener](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing/TraceEvent/TraceEvent/10_SimpleEventSourceMonitor.cs) for this `Microsoft-Windows-Battery` provider. The event has the entries `RemainingPercentage` to show the status and `PercentageChange` to see the change:

[image]

When you see this event and see the `-1` change for `PercentageChange`, run the program you want.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the script provided by DavidPostill does not work.
It's nice little script, but the code is either erratic or outdated.

### Here is the fixed one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem set threshold value
set _threshold=30
:start
rem get the battery charge
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1" %%i in (`wmic Path Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _charge=%%i
  echo !_charge!
  if !_charge! lss !_threshold! (
    echo threshold reached
    rem create a custom event in the application event log
    rem requires administrator privileges
    eventcreate /l APPLICATION /t WARNING /ID 999 /D "Battery charge has dropped below the threshold."
    goto :done
  ) else (
    rem wait for 1 minute then try again
    timeout /t 60 /nobreak
    goto :start
  )
)
:done
endlocal
```

I suggested this edit into DavidPostill's answer, but I don't know why it wasn't approved...

Comment: He set me on the right track, which is why I accepted his answer, but thank you very much! for your fixed script.

Comment: While fixing the code, I came to realise how buggy and erroneous the `findstr` is... Way too bad! Seriuosly, Microsoft? I'm impressed by DavidPostill's dirty little hack to get the job done.

Answer (score -1):

There is a much easier way to check battery level.  In navigation area just put mouse over the battery icon and it will give a percentage.

Comment: Yes,but thats really not what I wanted... I wanted to monitor battery level automatically and based on battery level do some stuff (again automatically)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: this guy must be an engineer!!!! ;-)