# How to set a sound notification of 100% battery?

Tags: windows-7, audio, battery, notifications, charging

We can set low/critical battery **sound notification** but I don't know how to set a full  battery **sound notification**,
Is there any way to do that?

EDIT : I agree to the point that not all laptops charge to 100%, then my question rephrases from 100% to 95%, or maybe to get a notification at some specified %age...

Comment: This might help you: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-laptop-battery-full-charge-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I cannot set a full battery sound notification, is there any way to do that?

Use the following batch file (Battery.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem set threshold value
set _threshold=95
:start
rem get the battery charge
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1" %%i in (`wmic Path Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _charge=%%i
  echo !_charge!
  if !_charge! geq !_threshold! (
    echo charge reached
    goto :done
    ) else (
    rem wait for 10 minutes then try again
    timeout /t 600 /nobreak
    goto :start
    )
  )
:done
endlocal
```

Notes:

- This batch file monitors the current battery percentage charge and prints "charge reached" when the charge reaches a user defined threshold value (in this case 95%). The batch file then ends. If the charge goes below the threshold, the user must manually run the batch file again.
- Set `_threshold` as required.
- Replace the `echo charge reached` command with a command to play your chosen sound.

  - If you want to create a user defined event (in the event log) instead of playing a sound then see my answer [Windows event id for battery level change](https://superuser.com/a/1162588/337631).
- Modify the `timeout` delay as required for your situation.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: That sure is useful...Thanks. BTW, I am guessing that there will be an open window all the time ? If that is the case then, Is there any way to have no window ?

Comment: @MukulKumar [How to run .BAT files invisibly, without displaying the Command Prompt window](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/)