# Write to Windows Event Viewer from log file

Tags: windows, logging, event-log, events

I have a log file "**logs.log**" that include the status of one of the applications, and I want to write these logs in Windows Events Viewer.

the output in that file as below:

```
24/01/2019 16:33:26   app(12744.13964) <SYSTEM> SERVICE.app.Activity: Stopping service...
```

Is there any way to write them in Windows Events Viewer?

BR

Answer (score 1):

You may use PowerShell to write to the Even Viewer.

The command to use is
[Write-EventLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1),
requiring administrator privileges.

Example: Write an event to the Application event log, using an elevated
PowerShell script:

```
PS C:\> Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "MyApp" -EventID 3001 -EntryType Information -Message "MyApp added a user-requested feature to the display." -Category 1 -RawData 10,20
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to write them in Windows Events Viewer?

You can write custom events to event logs using `EventCreate`.

For a working example see my answer [Windows event id for battery level change](https://superuser.com/a/1162588/337631).

---

#### EVENTCREATE

> Add a message to the Windows event log, requires administrator rights.
>
> ```
> Syntax
>       EVENTCREATE [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] /ID eventid
>             [/L logname] [/SO srcname] /T type /D description
>
> Key:
>     /S system         The remote system to connect to.
>
>     /U [domain\]user  User credentials under which to execute.
>
>     /P [password]     Password for user, will prompt if omitted.
>
>     /L logname        The event log to create an event in.
>
>     /T type           The type of event to create: SUCCESS, ERROR, WARNING, INFORMATION.
>
>     /SO source        The source to use for the event  A text string that represents the 
>                       application or component that is generating the event. 
>                       Default='eventcreate'
>
>     /ID id            Event ID, a number between 1 - 1000.
>
>     /D description    Description text for the new event.
>
>     /?                Help
> ```

Source [EventCreate - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/eventcreate.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EventCreate - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/eventcreate.html)
- [Create a Custom Event in the Windows Event Viewer • Raymond.CC](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-an-event-in-event-viewer/)